# How can compile-time string (BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING) be converted to runtime string?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

How to convert a `BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING` compile-time template parameter to "regular" string ?

Im using `BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING` to supply a string as template parameter (in one go/oneline).
The following compiles fine:

```
template<class T>
struct t{
};

t< BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING("hello") > tt_;
```

However I also need to display the string, etc. at some point, and I haven't found a way to construct some form of a runtime string, `std::string` / whatever from the compile-time type. I know this is possible, but how ?

Also, Im wondering if it's possible to pass as a template parameter value (eg. `const char*`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/metaparse/reference.html#metaparse.reference.alphabetical.boost_metaparse_string) for `BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING`, it generates a specialization of  `boost::metaparse::string` (documented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/metaparse/reference.html#string)). Since that's a simple class template, it's easy enough to convert:

```
template <char... Chars>
std::string toString(boost::metaparse::string<Chars...>) {
    return {Chars...};
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bd872e8711b5b01)

---

Alternately, if you don't feel like reinventing the wheel before looking through documentation (ahem), that's what [`boost::mpl::c_str`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/c-str.html) does.

Comment: I've found that mpl has a template called c_str, that works as well: `boost::mpl::c_str< BOOST_METAPARSE_STRING("hej") >::value` will yield a const char[] that can be used as a compile-time constant `const char *`

Comment: It almost feels like I stumpled upon the holy grail.. now I can create a define to pass in `const char*` template arguments... the only downside is the use of MACROs

Comment: @darune Welp, looks like I need a dose of RTFM! I added `c_str` to my answer :)